# How to convert MPG4 video?

Tags: 10.10, video-editor, transcode

What MPG4 converters are available for Ubuntu 10.10?

I have tried all that are in the Software Centre and none will work. I have a flip camera and it records in MPG4, which I have trouble with on Linux.

I don't mind whether the converters are graphical or command line.

thanks for all the help with this, finally got something to work, getting help is why i switched to Ubuntu.

Thanks everybody

Comment: It would help if you listed which ones you've tried so far, thanks!

Comment: have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras/addons? tried avidemux? handbrake? vlc?

Comment: If you still have problems even after trying the above mentioned (and maybe mplayer/mencoder) then a sample video would make it much easier to troubleshoot!

Answer (score 2):

avidemux works very well for converting various formats. It is not the easiest program out there, but it does the trick very well. Just open your MP4 file, adjust the output settings to the format you want and click save.

Answer (score 2):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is hands down the best video converter out there.

Comment: i seem not able to get this to even open for me, but thanks will keep trying to get installed

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg and mencoder decimate all.  i compile ffmpeg from source - there are directions for compilation on my blog here: http://aking1012.blogspot.com/2010/10/installing-ffmpeg-and-mplayer-from.html.  i have only had to resort to mencoder for some oddities with a couple of ogv videos, otherwise it's ffmpeg for me.  These are both command line.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Arista transcoder? is the best software for me

Comment: yes it did not like the mp4 at all, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

### [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

is the best video converter tool I know.

From the [details](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) page:

> **Supported Sources:**
>
> Any DVD-like source: VIDEO_TS folder, DVD image or real DVD (unencrypted--protection >methods including CSS are not supported internally and must be handled externally with >third-party software and libraries), and some .VOB and .TS files
>   Most any multimedia file it can get libavformat to read and libavcodec to decode.
>
> **Outputs:**
>
> File format: MP4 and MKV
>   Video: MPEG-4, H.264, or Theora
>   Audio: AAC, CoreAudio AAC (OS X Only), MP3, or Vorbis. AC-3 pass-through, DTS pass-thorugh >(MKV only)

You can install it via Software Center or `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk` [if you use their PPA:](https://edge.launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots)

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu lucid main` 
`deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu lucid main`